# CAGradientLayer type -- What's the Point?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-graphics, cagradientlayer

According the iOS [CAGradientLayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008320), the type property only has a single valid value, kCAGradientLayerAxial, which also happens to be the default.  The purpose of this property is a mystery to me, as I am wanting to implement a radial CAGradientLayer without overriding drawLayer: inContext, and was hoping to find something akin to kCAGradientLayerRadial.  Any illumination appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It allows Apple to add new types of gradient later without breaking API compatibility with existing programs.

Comment: It could be there to prevent people from adding a `-type` parameter to their subclasses, which would then break if Apple added it later. But I suspect that more types were planned, and were subsequently cut.